# ASP .NET MVC Web application WebSocket receive response from the server with a Keep alive echo message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, asp.net-core-6.0

I have written a program to connect to a WebSocket connection that provides details of schedules. This WebSocket server needs an echo message each 60 seconds to keep it alive. I have implemented that as well.

For receiving the schedules I have to send a command to the WebSocket in the following format:

```
string msg1 = "{\"header\":{\"method\":\"getSchedules\" }, \"content\":{\"initialDate\":\"" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + "\", \"finalDate\":\"" + dt.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + "\"}}";

string resp1 = await sendData(msg1);
var j1 = JObject.Parse(resp1);
var schedules= j1["data"]["list"];
```

I get the schedule for one day from this normally. But when I implemented a service class for Handling the Echo messages as below:

```
public class ScheduleService
    {
        private ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket;
        public int keepAlive = 0;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        public event Action<string> OnDataReceived;

        public ScheduleService()
        {
            clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();

        }

        public async Task StartWebSocketConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, _cancellationTokenSource.Token))
            {
                try
                {
                    clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
                    Uri serverUri = new Uri("wss://socketserver.io:443/");
                    await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(serverUri, CancellationToken.None);
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                    string token = "tokendata";
                    if (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        string msg = "{\"header\":{\"method\":\"Login\"},\"content\":{\"token\":\"" + token + "\"}}";
                        string resp = await sendData(msg);
                        //OnDataReceived?.Invoke(resp2);
                        _ = ReceiveMessagesAsync(clientWebSocket, linkedCts.Token);
                        _ = SendKeepAliveMessagesAsync(clientWebSocket, linkedCts.Token);
                        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
                        
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket connection error: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
        public async Task StopWebSocketConnection()
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            clientWebSocket?.Dispose();
        }
        

        public async Task<string> sendData(string msg)
        {
            Console.Write("Send Data");
            ArraySegment<byte> bytesToSend = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));
            await clientWebSocket.SendAsync(bytesToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            ArraySegment<byte> bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[4096]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, CancellationToken.None);
            string val = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(val);
            return val;
        }

        

        private async Task SendWebSocketMessage(string message)
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            await clientWebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        public async Task SendKeepAliveMessagesAsync(ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket, CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            while (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"header\":{\"method\":\"echo\"}}");
                await clientWebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cancellation);
                if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            }
        }
        private async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket, CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4096];

            while (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                WebSocketReceiveResult result = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), cancellation);

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                {
                    string message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {message}");
                    //OnDataReceived?.Invoke(message);
                }
                if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Now, all the response was going to the ReceiveMessagesAsync function and I am not able to get the list in the controller. Maybe sometimes, I will get the echo message reply.

How to handle this issue to keep the Keepalive function as it is but still send the messages to the WebSocket server and receive response from it?
There are some initial login message that is to be sent also.

Comment: Set the keep alive property in the WebSocket so you do not have to manually send the message : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.websocketoptions.keepaliveinterval?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: But it needs to send the command {\"header\":{\"method\":\"echo\"}} for keep alive. Is that possible from any properties?

Comment: It looks like the server had an option to enable Keep Alive.  You only have to send message once at beginning as a HTTP Header.  A Keep Alice is a datagram that is sent on the connection with a size of zero to keep the connection active.

Comment: In the documentation they mentioned to send the keepalive command to the server to get the heartbeat reply from the server. I am getting the value "60" from the login response. Using that keep alive interval I have to send the message. But, leave that, Maybe even if that is not there, how can i get the response properly in my controller code?

Comment: Well, Controllers is not the place to do that. As the controllers' lifetime is tied to the requests. I suggest having a singleton service that holds the WebSocket connection. And a hosted service that imports that WebSocket service and sends keep-alive requests periodically. And in your controller, you can also inject this service and send some requests.

Comment: You can't.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  A TCP datagram has three parts 1) IP Header 2) TCP header 3) Data.  A keep alive has no data and the size of the data in TCP header is zero.  The ethernet interface handle each datagram.  In c# the application layer does not get the keep alive.  The only way the server can detect the missing keep alive is when a timeout occurs on the interface when no data is received.

Comment: @Eldar, As you mentioned, I have added it as singleton for sending the ping command periodically, `builder.Services.AddSingleton<ScheduleService>();`  in Program.cs and `public OnlineController(ScheduleService _service)`  in the controller.

That is why the response is being redirected to the ReceiveMessagesAsync in the service.

@jdweng They maybe doing the keep alive mechanism some other way rather than the normal WebSocket keep alive method.